# Не могу зайти на сайт по домену asp.net core 7

Tags: iis, asp-net-core-mvc, domain

Asp.net core 7, IIS. Опубликовала сайт на сервере iis, могу заходить на него со всех устройств в локальной сети, но только по айпи и порту. Как сделать, чтобы можно было заходить по домену? Когда я вбиваю домен (который указывается при создании нового веб сайта в iis) в гугл, то открывается страница IIS "добро пожаловать". Если захожу в обзор сайта через iis, то ничего не загружается